# Lambda can't connect to CodeCommit from a subnet

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

I am working on a lambda function in node.js, this function needs to connect to CodeCommit, checkout a file from a specific branch in a specific repo, read some values and connect to a document DocumentDB cluster.

```
const codeCommit = new CodeCommit({region: "myRegion"});
const config = {
  filePath: "myFile",
  repositoryName: "myRepo",
  commitSpecifier: "myBranch"
};
const file = await codeCommit.getFile(config);
```

If I don't specify any subnet for this function, I am able to connect to CodeCommit and get my file, but I am not able to connect to DocumentDB, for this I was told my function needs to be in a private subnet.

The problem is that, when I set a subnet in "Configuration" -> "VPC" (public or private), I am able to connect to DocumentDB (I would expect from the private one only) but not to CodeCommit. For this I need to leave "Configuration" -> "VPC" empty.

The VPC I selected for lambda is the same as DocumentDB. I can connect to DocumentDB from EC2 as expected (same VPC).

Any idea on how to make this function connect to both CodeCommit and DocumentDB?

Comment: You probably need a NAT Gateway and an Internet Gateway for that VPC, or alternatively you could try with VPC Interface Endpoint for CodeCommit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambda functions must be deployed in private subnets, with the connectivity to AWS Public Services (i.e. CodeCommit) that must be granted by a NAT Gateway or Interface / Gateway VPC Endpoints.

So, you should:

- make sure that you're deploying the Lambdas in private subnets
- [configure a NAT Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/) with the appropriate route table entries, OR
- [configure an Interface Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/create-interface-endpoint.html) for CodeCommit

Souce: [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/?nc1=h_ls)

Comment: So I created an Endpoint, and for subnet I choose those where my lambda is (the private ones). As security group I am using one with outbound 0.0.0.0/0. Policy allow full access but I am still getting time out. Is there anything else I can double check?

Comment: What endpoints did you created? You should add, as endpoint: com.amazonaws.{region}.git-codecommit

Comment: Also I don't know how much big is the file that you're trying to download: if it's big you should increase the lambda timeout from the configuration panel (the default is 3 sec).

Comment: The file is short enought that I can receive it when lambda is not in the VPC. The doc here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/codecommit-and-interface-VPC.html) says to use com.amazonaws.us-east-1.codecommit when you want to use the SWK, Anyway I also tried com.amazonaws.us-east-1.git-codecommit with the same result.

Comment: It works. The policy AllowAll on the endpoint was in conflict with AWSCodeCommitReadOnly on the lambda execution role. I changed it to only allow Get* and I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use VPC Endpoint in order to communicate with CodeCommit without going over the internet:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/codecommit-and-interface-VPC.html